# One Column Referencing multiple Tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have one Table

> Table A (id_pk, ...)

Another Table B has 1:n relationship with A

> Table B (id_pk, id2_pk,....)

where id_pk is FK with Table A and id_pk together with id2_pk form composite PK for table B

Another Table C has 1:n relationship with A

> Table C (id_pk, id3_pk,....)

where id_pk is FK with Table A and id_pk together with id3_pk form composite PK for Table C

Can I have a table with this combination????

> Table D (id_pk, id2_pk, id3_pk, ....)

where id_pk together with id2_pk is FK with Table B, id_pk together with id3_pk is FK with Table C and id_pk, id2_pk, id3_pk together form a composite PK for Table D

Comment: Yes, just try it.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I tried creating the tables, there is no problem in that... I need to know about the drawbacks or any other better way to address my scenario

Comment: You will need to describe your scenario more specific. Right now I can only say that it's a valid relational schema. I can't say if it makes sense for your business domain.